# Join 3 C++ programs in series

Tags: c++, pipe

I am a Python and Lisp guy learning C++ and have come across a need to "concatenate" for lack of more precise terms, 3 C++ programs. I am unsure what would be the best way to do the following:

1) pocketsphinx takes input from the microphone, does real-time automatic speech recognition, outputs text to terminal, I want to send the output to the input of:

2) Chatscript, a chat program, which parses the incoming text (at the moment from keyboard) and generates a response which is sent to terminal, I want to send the output to the input of:

3) Festival, a text to speech that reads text input from the terminal and generates a voice output of that text.

I am exploring different ways to do this, as I understand it I could run pipes from pocketsphinx to Chatscript to festival, but some of what I've read leads me to believe this is a less than efficient way due to overhead. Also, regarding pipes, am I correct in thinking I would set 2 one way pipes (pid == 0) with the text outputs?

I think I could (once I learn a great deal more) combine all 3 programs (they are all open source) by essentially determining required libraries/files etc and "concatenating" the 3 void main()'s while changing the output statements?

Could someone offer some guidance/tutelage on this and opine as to which of these (or suggest other methods?) would be the most economical and effective?

regards, Richard

Comment: `./bin1 | ./bin2 | ./bin3` unnamed pipes?

Comment: If you're only passing text, especially if it's rate-limited by the speed that `festival` can talk, the efficiency of pipes is of absolutely no concern. Besides, pipes are quite efficient anyways!

Comment: All three used `void main()`? What a let down...

Comment: @ Chris, I haven't checked all three, but as I recall on Pocketsphinx and Chatscript, yes they do. Why is that a let down? Remember, I'm new to C++, I was under the impression that every C++ program had to have a main(), though it is sometimes main(int argc, char** argv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch for the cout or printf in the source, and add it to a buffer string variable, that will allow you to each time the buffer fills in, you can call the next program and execute it with the buffer gotten. If you dont need the "real time" processing, you can do what @zch pointed out, since if i recall (i might be wrong) pipes need the program to end before send the data to the next binary.

Comment: Ricardo, please allow me to restate in order to make sure I understand properly what you are saying, as it sounds quite probably to be the mot suitable way for my needs.   A buffer, being a section of memory temporarily set aside for specific use?? could have the output from ps (a string) assigned.  Cs could then retrieve the string from that buffer? can you point me to the docs that would teach me to do that?

Comment: No, pipes work fine, only outputs are buffered, but it they produce output real-time to terminal, they should also do that to pipe.

Comment: I think that does the trick then, and answers the question. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 1):

use "?" you can run several programs together 
use "|" use the previous output as input for the later program